# Displayin image with Ajax in Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to display image in a script. I get my data from action controller and   try to add my data name in img src= ? So how can I display image with my data ?

Here is my script:

> $(function () {
>           $.ajax({
>               type: "get", url: "Home/Oku", data: {}, dataType: "json", 
>               success: function (data) {
>
> img src="" + data[0] "width="150px" height="150px"/> ????? How can i display
>
> ```
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: how does your JSON look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
<img id="myimage" alt="Im being loaded with ajax"/>

$(function () { 
$.ajax({ 
    type: "get", 
    url: "Home/Oku", 
    data: {}, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        //sets the 'src' attribute for the image tag with id 'myimage'.
        $("img#myimage").attr("src", data);
        }
 });
```

}

Comment: allright but my image folder is src="../../banner_image/" so how can i add this route in attr("src") like ("src=../../banner_image/")

Comment: You should send the right path from your controller action. Can you show me your controller action?

Comment: public ActionResult Oku()
        {
            var query = from table in db.news select table.news_image_name;
            return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: I have no problem with my action method i get my value from model. I'm looking to give a route in src path

Comment: Your code is work but to add my src path like $("img#myimage").attr("src=../../banner_image", data); I have tried this but i miss something

Comment: I think u understand me wrong or i cant describe :) I mean im trying to give src of folder destination in $("img#myimage").attr("src", data);

Comment: I do understand. You should create the URL on the server, inside the action method. Just add the physical path to the image name your getting from the database.